# Support for downstream requests that replenish slower than ticks?

Tags: spring, rx-java, rx-java2, spring-webflux

My Spring 5.2 load application uses Spring WebClient to test REST API performance. Each API is called `n` times at a "fixed" `interval` in a loop:

```
AtomicLong rec = new AtomicLong();

for (long sendAt = System.nanoTime(), sent = 0; rec.get() < n;) {
    if (sent < n && System.nanoTime() >= sendAt) {
        webClient
            .post()
            .uri(uri)
            .accept(ACCEPT_TYPE)
            .header(SOME_HEADER, someHeaderValue())
            .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(obj)
            .exchange()
            .doOnSuccess(response -> rec.incrementAndGet())
            .subscribe()
            ;

        sendAt += interval;

        sent++;
    }
}
```

This works fine. Writing the equivalent in a declarative/reactive style, though, is evading me. Naively folding in the loop and the condition:

```
webClient
    .post()
    .uri(uri)
    .accept(ACCEPT_TYPE)
    .header(SOME_HEADER, someHeaderValue())
    .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(obj)
    .exchange()
    .repeatWhen(f -> Flux.interval(Duration.ofNanos(interval)))
    .take(n)
    .blockLast()
    ;
```

fails when the client can't keep up:

```
Could not emit tick 73685 due to lack of requests (interval doesn't support small downstream requests that replenish slower than the ticks)
```

So, what's the proper/reactive way to achieve what the imperative loop does?

Comment: If you don't mind losing ticks, apply `onBackpressureDrop`. If you don't want to lose ticks, you can use [Flowables.intervalBackpressure](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#flowablesintervalbackpressure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From David Karnok's comment; with his RxJava2 Extensions:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.akarnokd</groupId>
    <artifactId>rxjava2-extensions</artifactId>
    <version>0.20.8</version>
</dependency>
```

you can do:

```
webClient
    .post()
    .uri(uri)
    .accept(ACCEPT_TYPE)
    .header(SOME_HEADER, someHeaderValue())
    .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(obj)
    .exchange()
    .repeatWhen(f -> Flowables.intervalBackpressure(interval, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS))
    .take(n)
    .blockLast()
    ;
```

which does not fail when the client can't keep up but the `.header(SOME_HEADER, someHeaderValue())` is invoked only once (unlike the imperative loop); `someHeaderValue()` has to be updated on each repetition.